# Combine line and bar chart on one plot in R, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question has been asked on this platform quite many times but my situation is a bit different: There are negative values.
This is what I wish to achieve:

[image]

This is where I've got so far:

[image]

This is my code:

```
yearlyMedicalGWP <- tibble(
  Year = 2015:2019 |> as.character(), 
  Amount = c(29.5, 38.5, 38.3, 40.2, 42.3), 
  growth_rate = c(16.6, 30.5, -0.5, 4.8, 5.4)
)

transf_fact <- max(yearlyMedicalGWP$Amount) / max(yearlyMedicalGWP$growth_rate)

yearlyMedicalGWP |> 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Amount)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",  width = 0.5, color = "#003f5c", fill = "#003f5c",
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) + 
  geom_text(mapping = aes(label = Amount), vjust = -0.2, fontface = "bold") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = transf_fact * growth_rate), group = 1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / transf_fact, 
                                         name = "Second axis")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = transf_fact * growth_rate)) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(underline("Gross Written Premium")))) + 
  ylab("Amount in Kshs Billions") + 
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 0.65, 
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 15), 
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold.italic"), 
    axis.text = element_text(size = 13), 
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  )
```

The second axis should "move up" a bit so the negative point is not below the bars .

I also know (& understand) these types of charts may be misleading but I'm required to do this. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an offset to your transformation

```
transf_fact <- max(yearlyMedicalGWP$Amount) / max(yearlyMedicalGWP$growth_rate)
transf_offset <- 10
```

Then change your line and point to use

```
geom_line(aes(y = transf_fact * growth_rate + transf_offset), group = 1)
geom_point(aes(y = transf_fact * growth_rate + transf_offset))
```

and adjust your scale transformation

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / transf_fact - transf_offset, 
                                         name = "Second axis")) +
```

[image]